# Advanced Python Regex: how to evaluate and extract nested lists and numbers from a multiline string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to separate the elements from a multiline string:

```
lines = '''c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0   10 100.5 [1.5, 2]     [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]  [[a , bg], [5.5, ddd, edd]] 100.5
1   20 200.5 [2.5, 2]     [[20, 20.4], [d, 20, eee]]  [[a , bg], [7.5, udd, edd]] 200.5'''
```

My aim is to get a list `lst` such that:

```
# first value is index
lst[0] = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4','c5']
lst[1] = [0, 10, 100.5, [1.5, 2], [[10, 10.4], ['c', 10, 'eee']], [['a' , 'bg'], [5.5, 'ddd', 'edd']], 100.5 ]
lst[2] = [1, 20, 200.5, [2.5, 2], [[20, 20.4], ['d', 20, 'eee']], [['a' , 'bg'], [7.5, 'udd', 'edd']], 200.5 ]
```

My attempt so far is this:

```
import re

lines = '''c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0   10 100.5 [1.5, 2]     [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]  [[a , bg], [5.5, ddd, edd]] 100.5
1   20 200.5 [2.5, 2]     [[20, 20.4], [d, 20, eee]]  [[a , bg], [7.5, udd, edd]] 200.5'''


# get n elements for n lines and remove empty lines
lines = lines.split('\n')
lines = list(filter(None,lines))    

lst = []
lst.append(lines[0].split())


for i in range(1,len(lines)): 
  change = re.sub('([a-zA-Z]+)', r"'\1'", lines[i])
  lst.append(change)

for i in lst[1]:
  print(i)
```

How to fix the regex?

**Update**
Test datasets

```
data = """
    orig  shifted  not_equal  cumsum  lst
0     10      NaN       True       1  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
1     10     10.0      False       1  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
2     23     10.0       True       2  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
"""

# Gives: ValueError: malformed node or string:

data = """
    Name Result Value
0   Name1   5   2
1   Name1   5   3
2   Name2   11  1
"""
# gives same error


data = """
product  value
0       A     25
1       B     45
2       C     15
3       C     14
4       C     13
5       B     22
"""
# gives same error

data = '''
    c0 c1
0   10 100.5
1   20 200.5
'''
# works perfect
```

Comment: Since the type is different (`c0` is string, 10 is number ...), I don't think there is a regex for this task. It will be much easier if you post-process your results

Comment: Is the source tab-delimited? Rows 2 and 3 look like they could possibly be but Row 1 doesn't

Comment: @kerwei the source is space limited. Multiple spaces are allowed.

Comment: I presume the square-bracket groups can be arbitrarily nested?

Comment: @Tomalak Correct. The groups can be nested arbitrarily.

Comment: Then this is impossible to do with regex. Arbitrary balanced nesting is a thing regex cannot handle.

Comment: @Tomalak Alright, then is there any way to do upto only two nested groups as like in above example? Help will be appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, I've updated my answer with a Python version.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for your great effort. It means a lot.

Comment: It was fun to work it out, you're welcome. Deal: Follow-up questions you might have you try to work out on your own. :) I would recommend building a super simple parser from scratch, for example one that takes a line of numbers and returns the sum, Just to get an understanding how the various parts in Parsimonious work together.

Comment: You can also try some modifications. For example, currently all numbers are returned as floats. Maybe you want ints, too. Modify the function that produces numbers to be a bit smarter. Maybe you want strings that can start with a digit, or maybe you want \t to be a valid delimiter. Modify the parser grammar to allow that. And so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this task is impossible to do with regex. Regex is fundamentally unable to handle nested constructs. What you need is a parser.

One of the ways to create a parser is [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), which lets you set up a list of tokens and their relations to each other in a declarative language. This parser definition is then turned into an actual parser that can handle the described input. When parsing succeeds, you will get back a tree structure with all the items properly nested.

For demonstration purposes, I've used the JavaScript implementation peg.js, which has an [online demo page](https://pegjs.org/online) where you can live-test parsers against some input. This parser definition:

```
{
    // [value, [[delimiter, value], ...]] => [value, value, ...]
    const list = values => [values[0]].concat(values[1].map(i => i[1]));
}
document
    = line*
line "line"
    = value:(item (whitespace item)*) whitespace? eol { return list(value) }
item "item"
    = number / string / group
group "group"
    = "[" value:(item (comma item)*) whitespace? "]" { return list(value) }
comma "comma"
    = whitespace? "," whitespace?
number "number"
    = value:$[0-9.]+ { return +value }
string "string"
    = $([^ 0-9\[\]\r\n,] [^ \[\]\r\n,]*)
whitespace "whitespace"
    = $" "+
eol "eol"
    = [\r]? [\n] / eof
eof "eof"
    = !.
```

can understand this kind of input:

```
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0   10 100.5 [1.5, 2]     [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]  [[a , bg], [5.5, ddd, edd]]
1   20 200.5 [2.5, 2]     [[20, 20.4], [d, 20, eee]]  [[a , bg], [7.5, udd, edd1]]
```

and produces this object tree (JSON notation):

```
[
    ["c0", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"],
    [0, 10, 100.5, [1.5, 2], [[10, 10.4], ["c", 10, "eee"]], [["a", "bg"], [5.5, "ddd", "edd"]]],
    [1, 20, 200.5, [2.5, 2], [[20, 20.4], ["d", 20, "eee"]], [["a", "bg"], [7.5, "udd", "edd1"]]]
]
```

i.e.

- an array of lines,
- each of which is an array of values,
- each of which can be either a number, or a string, or another array of values

This tree structure can then be handled by your program.

The above would work for example with node.js to turn your input into JSON. The following minimal JS program accepts data from STDIN and writes the parsed result to STDOUT:

```js
// reference the parser.js file, e.g. downloaded from https://pegjs.org/online
const parser = require('./parser');

var chunks = [];

// handle STDIN events to slurp up all the input into one big string
process.stdin.on('data', buffer => chunks.push(buffer.toString()));
process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    var text = chunks.join('');
    var data = parser.parse(text);
    var json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    process.stdout.write(json);
});

// start reading from STDIN
process.stdin.resume();
```

Save it as `text2json.js` or something like that and redirect (or pipe) some text into it:

```
# input redirection (this works on Windows, too)
node text2json.js < input.txt > output.json

# common alternative, but I'd recommend input redirection over this
cat input.txt | node text2json.js > output.json
```

There are PEG parser generators for Python as well, for example https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious. The parser creation language differs between implementations, so the above can only be used for peg.js, but the principle is exactly the same.

---

**EDIT** I've dug into Parsimonious and recreated the above solution in Python code. The approach is the same, the parser grammar is the same, with a few tiny syntactical changes.

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    document   = line*
    line       = whitespace? item (whitespace item)* whitespace? eol
    item       = group / number / boolean / string
    group      = "[" item (comma item)* whitespace? "]"
    comma      = whitespace? "," whitespace?
    number     = "NaN" / ~"[0-9.]+"
    boolean    = "True" / "False"
    string     = ~"[^ 0-9\[\]\r\n,][^ \[\]\r\n,]*"
    whitespace = ~" +"
    eol        = ~"\r?\n" / eof
    eof        = ~"$"
    """)

class DataExtractor(NodeVisitor):
    @staticmethod
    def concat_items(first_item, remaining_items):
        """ helper to concat the values of delimited items (lines or goups) """
        return first_item + list(map(lambda i: i[1][0], remaining_items))

    def generic_visit(self, node, processed_children):
        """ in general we just want to see the processed children of any node """
        return processed_children

    def visit_line(self, node, processed_children):
        """ line nodes return an array of their processed_children """
        _, first_item, remaining_items, _, _ = processed_children
        return self.concat_items(first_item, remaining_items)

    def visit_group(self, node, processed_children):
        """ group nodes return an array of their processed_children """
        _, first_item, remaining_items, _, _ = processed_children
        return self.concat_items(first_item, remaining_items)

    def visit_number(self, node, processed_children):
        """ number nodes return floats (nan is a special value of floats) """
        return float(node.text)

    def visit_boolean(self, node, processed_children):
        """ boolean nodes return return True or False """
        return node.text == "True"

    def visit_string(self, node, processed_children):
        """ string nodes just return their own text """
        return node.text
```

The `DataExtractor` is responsible for traversing the tree and pulling out data from the nodes, returning lists of strings, numbers, booleans, or NaN.

The `concat_items()` function performs the same task as the `list()` function in the Javascript code above, the other functions also have their equivalents in the peg.js approach, except that peg.js integrates them directly into the parser definition and Parsimonious expects definitions in a separate class, so it's a bit wordier in comparison, but not too bad.

Usage, assuming an input file called "data.txt", also mirrors the JS code:

```
de = DataExtractor()

with open("data.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    text = f.read()

tree = grammar.parse(text)
data = de.visit(tree)
print(data)
```

Input:

```
orig shifted not_equal cumsum lst
0 10 NaN True 1 [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]
1 10 10.0 False 1 [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]
2 23 10.0 True 2 [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]
```

Output:

```
[
    ['orig', 'shifted', 'not_equal', 'cumsum', 'lst'],
    [0.0, 10.0, nan, True, 1.0, [[10.0, 10.4], ['c', 10.0, 'eee']]],
    [1.0, 10.0, 10.0, False, 1.0, [[10.0, 10.4], ['c', 10.0, 'eee']]], 
    [2.0, 23.0, 10.0, True, 2.0, [[10.0, 10.4], ['c', 10.0, 'eee']]]
]
```

In the long run, I would expect this approach to be more maintainable and flexible than regex hackery. Adding explicit support for NaN and for booleans (which the peg.js-Solution above does not have - there they are parsed as strings) for example was easy.

Comment: Thanks a ton. But i am quite unfamiliar with js, is there equivalent python code? That would help a lot.

Comment: The implication kind of was: If you want to do the same in Python, you are free to translate the parser definition into a form that e.g. Parsimonious can understand. :) The parser structure itself would be the same, so you can use it as a guide. It would be educational (and rewarding!) to try. Personally I've never worked with Parsimonious, so answering this in Python code would have taken me a lot longer, plus I primarily wanted to get a proof-of-concept level answer to make a point, so I used something that was quick and interactive.

Comment: @astro123 If you only want to parse the input, no questions asked, put the above into the peg.js online version, download the resulting JS file (bottom right, "Download parser code", you will get a JS module) and make a tiny node.js script that imports it. I'll add such a script, give me a minute.

Comment: @astro123 Updated answer with a tiny piece of JS code that gets the job done. Loading JSON in Python is a piece of cake, if you want to continue there.

Comment: I honestly disagree that you can't do it with regular expressions - see my answer below (and I am very open to discussions :)

Comment: Definately the better choice in the long run!

Answer (score 5):

I honestly disagree that it is impossible to do with a regular expression. One might state more precisely that it is not possible with regular expressions *alone*.
See the following code which yields what you want and read the explanation further down.

### Code

```
import regex as re
from ast import literal_eval

data = """
c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
0   10 100.5 [1.5, 2]     [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]]  [[a , bg], [5.5, ddd, edd]] 100.5
1   20 200.5 [2.5, 2]     [[20, 20.4], [d, 20, eee]]  [[a , bg], [7.5, udd, edd]] 200.5
"""

# regex definition
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<item>[.\w]+)
        (?<list>\[(?:[^][\n]*|(?R))+\])
    )
    (?&list)|(?&item)
    ''', re.X)

# unquoted item
item_rx = re.compile(r"(?<!')\b([a-z][.\w]*)\b(?!')")

# afterwork party
def afterwork(match):
    match = item_rx.sub(r"'\1'", match)
    return literal_eval(match)

matrix = [
    [afterwork(item.group(0)) for item in rx.finditer(line)]
    for line in data.split("\n")
    if line
]

print(matrix)
```

This yields

```
[['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'], [0, 10, 100.5, [1.5, 2], [[10, 10.4], ['c', 10, 'eee']], [['a', 'bg'], [5.5, 'ddd', 'edd']], 100.5], [1, 20, 200.5, [2.5, 2], [[20, 20.4], ['d', 20, 'eee']], [['a', 'bg'], [7.5, 'udd', 'edd']], 200.5]]
```

### Explanation

First, we import the newer `regex` module and the function `literal_eval` from the `ast` module which will be needed to transform the found matches in actual code. The newer `regex` module has far more power than the `re` module and provides recursive functionality and the powerful (yet not very well known) `DEFINE` construct for subroutines.

We define two types of elements, the first being a "simple" item, the latter being a "list item", see [**the demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/81lNeM/1).

In a second step we add quotes for those element who needs them (that is, unquoted elements starting with a character). Everything is fed into `literal_eval` and then saved within the list comprehension.

Comment: @Jan Agreed, nice work. I've known about the regex module and the PCRE extended/recursive it brings. (I've not known about subroutines, though!). I was a bit hesitant to say "it's impossible with regex" because of this, but of course it's a nice coincidence that the structures present here can be thrown at `literal_eval()` for parsing almost unmodified. Sneaky. ;)

Comment: @Jan This works perfectly for the above data, when I tested the code for another data `data = """
    orig  shifted  not_equal  cumsum  lst
0     10      NaN       True       1  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
1     10     10.0      False       1  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
2     23     10.0       True       2  [[10, 10.4], [c, 10, eee]] 
"""` it gives me `ValueError: malformed node or string:`. How to avoid the error?

Comment: You might want to try my parser-based solution ;)

Comment: @Jan Thanks a lot, will wait for it. It already solved most of the cases. Only True/False and NaNs are not read as the list values.

Comment: It's symptomatic for regex-based parsing of complex input: "it almost works, we *just* need to add a little bit more regex to it here, and here, but it almost works!" - wash, rinse, repeat. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: To be honest, this looks more like a Job for [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) but haven't checked yet. Were else do `NaN`s and list structures occur in a file?

Comment: Hm, on first glance, `numpy.loadtext` does not seem to handle nested structures, either.

Comment: Can you clarify, `regex` is a third-party package, correct?

Comment: @pylang: Yup. As well as `pandas`, `numpy`, etc.